# error when I use the same variable name in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I know using the same variable name is a bad practice.

I just want to know why this happened technically.

```
In [1]: a=[1,2,3]

In [2]: b=[4,5,6]

In [3]: [a for a in a]
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3]

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]

In [5]: [(a,c) for a in a for c in b]
Out[5]: [(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]

In [6]: [(a,b) for a in a for b in b]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bac0ec331d24> in <module>()
----> 1 [(a,b) for a in a for b in b]

<ipython-input-6-bac0ec331d24> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [(a,b) for a in a for b in b]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://bugs.python.org/issue31126.

> It's consistent with the behavior of generator expressions: